# VB trouble instantiating object when constructor has a structure data type

Tags: vb.net

I really like the community.  I am trying to teach myself vb by trying out what I have learned.  I am learning how to use enum's, structures and objects so I thought I would mix them all together ti get a better understanding of whats going on.  I am using a Card as an example (been practicing everything with cards)

I created an enum called Suit

```
   Public Enum suit As Integer
     Spades = 0
     Diamonds =1
     Clovers = 2
     Hearts = 3
   End Enum
```

Next I created structure that uses the enum data type I just created

```
Public structure cardValue

    Public cardSuit As suit <--- enum 
    Public cardName As Integer

 End Structure
```

Lastely I created a class of a card

```
 Public Class Card

   Private actualCard As cardValue

    Get 

      Return actualCard

    End Get

    Set(value As cardValue)

    End Set

 actualCard=value

 End Property

 Sub New (actualCard As cardValue)

     Me.actualCard = actualCard

 End Sub

End Class
```

Now here is my problem

When I goto create a object of the class Card I am not sure how to pass the arguments into the constructor?

**Dim myCard As Card = New Card ( I want Spade , and a card value of 10 )**

not sure how to pass it a Value, everything I try I get errors of not valid type

I am also not sure how to make the code grey, I am very sorry about that.

Comment: Get rid of *cardValue*, make Suit and Name properties of the class.  Now it is easy.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the whole point is I am trying to learn how to do it this way.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  You are missing the `Public Property NameOfYourProperty As cardValue` on your property.  And the `End Set`.

Comment: Sorry about that, i retyped it on my home PC (its on my laptop)

Comment: Dim myCard As Card = New Card ( how do i pass a value here)

Comment: Just pass the value there, for enums that would be `EnumName.ValueYouWant`.

Comment: I dont see much value in the cardValue structure (esp AS a struct rather than class).  it could be just `New(cardSuit as suitEnum, v As Int32)`.  Which begs the question why `Class Card` has to be told which card to create. If there is a Deck in this, there should be a List(of Cards) representing the shuffled deck and NewCard would just be the next one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

With your actual constructor you could do :

```
Dim c As New Card(New cardValue With {.cardSuit = suit.Spades, .cardName = 10})
```

But the easiest way would be to change your constructor :

```
Public Sub New(suitValue As suit, cardValue As Integer)
    ActualCard = New cardValue With {.cardSuit = SuitValue, .cardName = CardValue}
End Sub
```